# ffprobe/ffmpeg: know if a input is a video, image or audio

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I need to know if a input file is a Video, Audio or a Image file.

Some of the audio files contains an video stream and a audio stream, so, I can't check the streams to know if it's a video or a audio.

Is there any way to know that?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used class File.extension to know the extension of the file like:

```
if (f.extension == "jpg" || f.extension == "jpeg") {
 //image
}
```

It works for me.